# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.fetchData().then')

Tags: react-native

native function to draw a scene inside the main render. But i get error as the title of this question ( undefined is not and object...)

This is my function block :

```js
 fetchData() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;           
        
        fetch(REQUEST_URL+'&'+'cabnum='+params.cabreg)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {           
             //alert(params.cabreg);
             Alert.alert('','Your driver is :'+responseData[0].driver);
            return responseData;
  
            }).done();
        }
```

and my main render is this :

```js
render() {
            const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
             
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{params.cabreg}</Text>
                    <View>{this.fetchData()
                            .then((responseData)=>{                                
                                    return(<View style={styles1.rightContainer}> 
                                            <Image source={{uri: responseData[0].image}} style={styles1.thumbnail} /> 
                                            <View style={{flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'center'}}>
                                                <Text style={styles1.title}>{responseData[0].reg}</Text>
                                                <Text style={styles1.driver}>Driver:{responseData[0].driver}</Text>
                                                <Text style={styles1.driver}>Cab Type:{responseData[0].ctype}</Text>
                                                <Text style={styles1.driver}>Contact:{responseData[0].contact}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                            </View>
                                            );
                                    }
                            )  
                        }
                    </View>
                </View>
            ); 
        }
```

Comment: is your function `fetchData` in the same file as your render method ?

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp, yes in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way of rendering the response data to the view.

Try this:

```
render()
{
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state

return (
    <View>
        <Text>
            {params.cabreg}
        </Text>
        <View>
            {this.fetchData()}
        </View>
    </View>
)
}
```

and the function like this :

```
fetchData()
{
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state

fetch(REQUEST_URL + '&' + 'cabnum=' + params.cabreg)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
        //alert(params.cabreg);
        Alert.alert('', 'Your driver is :' + responseData[0].driver)
        return (
            <View style={styles1.rightContainer}>
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: responseData[0].image }}
                    style={styles1.thumbnail}
                />
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Text style={styles1.title}>
                        {responseData[0].reg}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles1.driver}>
                        Driver:{responseData[0].driver}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles1.driver}>
                        Cab Type:{responseData[0].ctype}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles1.driver}>
                        Contact:{responseData[0].contact}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    })
    .done()
}
```

Comment: did you check the code ? Its almost what i did. And your code dont work atall. It gives a blank screen, which me also got. Thank you anyways.

Comment: if its giving a blank screen and not any error that means there is some styling issue.I ll recheck it tomorrow.